# Github: find issues where assignee IS NOT a specific user

Tags: github

How do I filter the issue list where the assignee IS NOT a specific user? Something like `assignee:!userA` (although that doesn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can use the "-" as in -assignee:userA

More info on [Filter Qualifiers Based On Exclusion](https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax/#filter-qualifiers-based-on-exclusion)